Low-level call execution reverted
I have a Solidity contract deployed here.
When I attempt to calculate the gas for the transaction I get an execution reverted error.
According to Etherscan Gas Oracle API called in another routine the proposed Gas in Wei is 857664468 or 0.000000000857664468 ETH. My wallet holds 0.026389996078916648 ETH.
So it's not insufficient balance in the wallet.
Is there anything obviously wrong with the code below?
func main() {
    wallet := "0x478d21c5167CB66AdEDAFA8D72D1f3757F6e6206"
    from := "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"
    to := "0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F"
    contract := "0xcBc57F275dB5fd2F4da20882fCa443B9cd302eCD"
    token := "0x46101fbe580940c7dd2d2879662bc98954b5edd1"
    amount := 17720

    gas := gasCalculated(wallet, from, to, contract, token, amount)
    fmt.Println("gas", gas)
}

func gasCalculated(wallet, from, to, contract, token string, amount int) *big.Int {
    apiKey := "YOUR Infura API KEY"
    url := "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/" + apiKey
    client, err := ethclient.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to the Ethereum client: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    gasCostProposedGasWei := 857664468
    // from https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=gastracker&action=gasoracle&apikey=YourApiKeyToken called in another routine

    fmt.Println("gas.Cost.ProposedGasWei", gasCostProposedGasWei) //-->gas.Cost.ProposedGasWei 1022582486
    fmt.Println("wallet", wallet)                                 //-->0x478d21c5167CB66AdEDAFA8D72D1f3757F6e6206
    fmt.Println("from", from)                                     //-->0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D
    fmt.Println("to", to)                                         //-->0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F
    fmt.Println("contract", contract)                             //-->0xcBc57F275dB5fd2F4da20882fCa443B9cd302eCD
    fmt.Println("token", token)                                   //-->0x46101fbe580940c7dd2d2879662bc98954b5edd1
    fmt.Println("amount", amount)                                 //-->17720

    // Specify the sender and recipient addresses
    walletAddress := common.HexToAddress(wallet)
    fromAddress := common.HexToAddress(from)
    toAddress := common.HexToAddress(to)
    contractAddress := common.HexToAddress(contract)
    tokenAddress := common.HexToAddress(token)

    contractABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(flashLoanReceiverABI())) // Correct ABI fetching
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to fetch ABI:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    addressType, err := abi.NewType("address", "", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create address type: %v", err)
    }

    addresses := abi.Arguments{
        {Type: addressType},
        {Type: addressType},
        {Type: addressType},
    }

    packedData, err := addresses.Pack(fromAddress, toAddress, tokenAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to pack addresses: %v", err)
    }
// also tried this verison since the baseTokenAddress & assetTokenAddress are the same
//data, err := contractABI.Pack("onFlashLoan", walletAddress, tokenAddress, big.NewInt(int64(amount)), big.NewInt(0), packedData)
    data, err := contractABI.Pack("onFlashLoan", walletAddress, contractAddress, big.NewInt(int64(amount)), big.NewInt(0), packedData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ABI packing failed:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    callMsg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        From:     fromAddress,
        To:       &contractAddress,
        GasPrice: nil, // Let the client decide the gas price
        Value:    big.NewInt(0),
        Data:     data,
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    /*  */
    header, err := client.HeaderByNumber(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get header:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    // Perform the low-level eth_call to check the transaction
    var result hexutil.Bytes
    result, err = client.CallContract(ctx, callMsg, header.Number)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Low-level call %v\n", err) //<--Low-level call execution reverted
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    // Decode or inspect `result` to understand the failure
    fmt.Printf("Low-level call result: %x\n", result)

    // Estimate the gas required for the transaction
    gasLimit, err := client.EstimateGas(ctx, callMsg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to estimate gas:", err)
        return big.NewInt(0)
    }

    return big.NewInt(int64(gasLimit))
}

// Deployed contract https://etherscan.io/address/0xcBc57F275dB5fd2F4da20882fCa443B9cd302eCD
func flashLoanReceiverABI() string {
    return `[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"initiator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"baseTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"fee","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onFlashLoan","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"updateOwner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]`
}


Please share a runnable example with more code so that I can test that on my end, including the ABI.

@MilaA Updated code base to standalone runnable code, you just need your Infura API key.

I see, taking a look at it right now, thank you, @pigfox

The reason of the revert is that you're using the address of your FlashloanReceiver contract while creating the packedData in this line:
packedData, err := addresses.Pack(fromAddress, toAddress, contractAddress)

And, inside the body of the onFlashLoan() function of your contract, you're decoding the last param of type bytes i.e., data (the one that you're passing as packedData from your script) as:
(address buyDexAddress, address sellDexAddress, address assetTokenAddress) = abi.decode(data, (address, address, address));

Which means the assetTokenAddress is assigned as the contractAddress, and then you're instantiating that using the IERC20 interface:
IERC20 assetToken = IERC20(assetTokenAddress);

Since, the contract code of FlashloanReceiver is not matching with the format of any ERC20 contract code, that's why it's getting reverted.
So, you need to pass the correct address of the expected assetTokenAddress in the last argument of the addresses.Pack() while creating the packedData.

I switched the variables based on you suggestion. The code above is updated. But the error remains.

@pigfox, the base token address can’t be same as the asset token address.

How do you swap a token on one Dex to another Dex then?
